# How to display a div next to a paragraph "without floating the div to right"?

Tags: jquery, html, css

From the following code I want the div `#solution` to be displayed next to the paragraph, *without floating #solution to the right side*.

***The reason is that*** I DO NOT want to align `#solution` to the right side of the screen, but I want it to be next to the paragraph. *So that the drop-down list which contains the answer should 'look like' an inline part or continuation of the question statement.*

**How can I achieve that?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="statement" style="">
            <div><p>Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement </p></div>
        </div>
        <div id="solution" style="">
            <select class="answer">
                <div><option value="">choose one</option></div>
                <div class="r0">
                    <option id="q3:1_answer0" name="q3:1_answer" value="0">FirstOption</option>
                </div>
                <div class="r0">
                    <option id="q3:1_answer1" name="q3:1_answer" value="1">SecondOption</option>
                </div>
                <div class="r0">
                    <option id="q3:1_answer2" name="q3:1_answer" value="2">ThirdOption</option>
                </div>
        </select>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried display: inline-block ?

Comment: If you can use [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) and share a link here, it would be helpful.

Comment: @Gofilord I actually confused it a bit. I just resolved it. Posting it as an answer so that it can be helpful for any future visitors. Here is the [updated JSFiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/N47eC/1/)

Comment: Thank you everyone for the responses, I apologise for confusion in the question. The div's did not need to be adjacent to each other, but rather wanted to align the `<select>` element next to the `<p>` element. `display:inline;` did here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question, this is what was needed:-

> So that the drop-down list which contains the answer should 'look like' an inline part or continuation of the question statement.

And just solved this way: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N47eC/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
            <div><p style="display:inline;">Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement Question statement </p><div id="solution" style="display: inline;">
            <select class="answer">
                <div><option value="">choose one</option></div>
                <div class="r0">
                    <option id="q3:1_answer0" name="q3:1_answer" value="0">FirstOption</option>
                </div>
                <div class="r0">
                    <option id="q3:1_answer1" name="q3:1_answer" value="1">SecondOption</option>
                </div>
                <div class="r0">
                    <option id="q3:1_answer2" name="q3:1_answer" value="2">ThirdOption</option>
                </div>
        </select>
        </div></div>


    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use table as parent div, table-cell as child div.

display:[table-cell](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

```
<div style="display:table">
        <div id="statement" style="display:table-cell">...</div>
        <div id="solution" style="display:table-cell">...</div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KD5PF/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Position: Absolute` in the CSS code.

```
#statement {
    position: absolute;
    height: ...; <!-- Definit a height -->
    width: ...; <!-- Definit a width -->
}

#solution {
    position: absolute;
    height: ...; <!-- Definit a height -->
    width: ...; <!-- Definit a width -->
}
```

After that, you place each `div` with `margin` !